# How can I use word advise as a verb in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it correct to say that:

> It is **advised** not to exercise after having a meal.

Answer (score 3):

Idiomatically, people are [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%20is%20advised%20not%20to%2CIt%20is%20recommended%20not%20to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20advised%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20recommended%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0) to use *It is **recommended** [not] to [do something]* if they're going to use the "dummy **it**" form at all (but it's usually [***We*** are **advised** not to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20advised%20not%20to%2CI%20am%20recommended%20not%20to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20advised%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0), with an explicit subject).

The "preferred syntax" for *It is advised / recommended / suggested / urged / counseled / advocated / etc. [some favoured "action"]* is neither clearly defined nor consistently observed. Perhaps because of that, native speakers often rephrase a somewhat "klunky" utterance such as *It is advised to wait* to...

> *It is advised **that** you [should] wait.* (introduce a "subjunctive" verb)
>    *You are advised **to** wait.* (introduce an infinitive verb, avoid "dummy **it**")
>    ***Waiting*** is advised. (recast "the action advised" to be the grammatical subject)
>    etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a correct thing to say, and

> *(be) advised* + [not] + to infinitive

is a pattern commonly found in published writing.

If you search online for "advised not to exercise", you will find many examples. Include the quotation marks in your search.